# How to break table into two without losing performance?

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, optimization, normalization

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/174047/14731, splitting away infrequently-needed columns frees up the cache allowing faster retrieval of the commonly-used columns.

I've got a table whose columns are *always* retrieved together, but I'd still like to split them for design reasons (reduce duplication across multiple tables, improve code reuse). For example, I've got different tables that use the same permission scheme. Instead of adding permission columns to each table, I'd like to use a foreign key to reference a separate permission-scheme table.

I've populated MySQL with 1 million rows, ran queries against both versions, and discovered that the version with a JOIN is ~3x slower (0.9 seconds vs 2.9 seconds).

Here are my tables:

```
original
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    first BIGINT NOT NULL,
    second BIGINT NOT NULL,
    third BIGINT NOT NULL
);
part1
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    first BIGINT NOT NULL,
    second BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
part2
(
    link BIGINT NOT NULL,
    third BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (link) REFERENCES part1(id)
);
```

Here are my queries:

```
SELECT first, second, third FROM original;
SELECT part1.first, part1.second, part2.third FROM part1, part2 WHERE part2.link = part1.id;
```

**Is there any way to reduce the performance overhead of the split design?**

---

If you want to reproduce this test on your side, you can use the following Java application to generate the SQL script to populate the database:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        final int COUNT = 1_000_000;
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/import.sql"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
                out.println("INSERT INTO original VALUES (" + i + ", " + i + ", 0);");
            out.println("INSERT INTO original VALUES (" + (COUNT - 2) + ", " + (COUNT - 1) +
                ", 1);");
            out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
            {
                out.println("INSERT INTO part1 (first, second) VALUES (" + i + ", " + i + ");");
                out.println("INSERT INTO part2 VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 0);");
            }
            out.println("INSERT INTO part1 (first, second) VALUES (" + (COUNT - 2) + ", " +
                (COUNT - 1) + ");");
            out.println("INSERT INTO part2 VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 1);");
            out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please run `SELECT MAX(id) FROM part1;` and tells us the value.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA The value is `1000001`.

Comment: Is part2.link a FOREIGN KEY that references part1.id?

Comment: @Vérace yes. Doesn't the table definition say as much? Or did I make a typo somewhere?

Comment: Ooops - blind, sorry - my bad!

Comment: `part2` does not have a primary key?

Comment: @ypercube, no it does not. My use-case does not need it but even if we had one, it wouldn't help anything because we are iterating all rows in `part2` linearly. I don't think a primary key would help anything performance-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the reason for using normalization to a limited extent, and after performance testing. Normalization comes at cost of joins (sorting). The main purpose of DWH on 5NF is to store data safely, not to retrieve it quickly.

**Alternative 1**
There is a concept of Materialized View: a view that saved on hard drive. MySQL does not provide it out of the box, but this article - [Materialized views with MySQL](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) - explains how this functionality can be recreated with a SP updating/refreshing a table.

> A Materialized View (MV) is the pre-calculated (materialized) result
>   of a query. Unlike a simple VIEW the result of a Materialized View is
>   stored somewhere, generally in a table. Materialized Views are used
>   when immediate response is needed and the query where the Materialized
>   View bases on would take to long to produce a result. Materialized
>   Views have to be refreshed once in a while. It depends on the
>   requirements how often a Materialized View is refreshed and how actual
>   its content is. Basically a Materialized View can be refreshed
>   immediately or deferred, it can be refreshed fully or to a certain
>   point in time. MySQL does not provide Materialized Views by itself.

**Alternative 2**
You can try to achieve your design by doing things other way round. Instead of splitting main table, create 2-3 views or tables that come from the main one. This way you'll have normalized tables for star schema with distinct values and also you'll keep the main fast table.

**Performance tuning** is always about the trade off between CPU (time), RAM, and IO (throughput or space). In this case it is between CPU and IO.

Answer (score 1):

## OPTION #1 : Use INT UNSIGNED instead of BIGINT

If the fields will not exceed `4,294,967,295`, change them to `INT UNSIGNED`

```
ALTER TABLE part1
    MODIFY COLUMN id     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MODIFY COLUMN first  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    MODIFY COLUMN second INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE part2
    MODIFY COLUMN link  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    MODIFY COLUMN third INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Smaller datatypes, especially for JOIN keys, will make the same query go faster.

If the fields will not exceed `16,777,215`, use`MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` for even smaller columns.

## OPTION #2 : Use a Bigger Join Buffer

Add this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
join_buffer_size = 16M
```

Then, login to MySQL and run

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL join_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 16;
```

MySQL restart not needed.

See MySQL Documentation about [**join_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size)

## OPTION #3 : Make sure `link` is indexed

Since you have a `FOREIGN KEY` reference, this is a rather moot point. If you do not have the `FOREIGN KEY`, make sure link is indexed:

```
ALTER TABLE part2 ADD UNIQUE KEY (link);
```

## Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2014-08-22 17:13 EDT

I created my own version of the Sample Data using this:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS GILI; CREATE DATABASE GILI;
USE GILI
create table original 
(
    id mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment,
    first mediumint unsigned not null,
    second mediumint unsigned not null,
    third mediumint unsigned not null,
    primary key (id)
);
create table part1 like original;
alter table part1 drop column third;
create table part2 select third from original;
alter table part2 add link mediumint unsigned not null first;
alter table part2 add primary key (link);
insert into original (first,second,third) values (1,2,3);
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into original (first,second,third) select first,second,third from original;
insert into part1 (id,first,second) select id,first,second from original;
insert into part2 (link,third) select id,third from original;
select count(1) from (select * from original) A;
select count(1) from (select * from part1 inner join part2 on part1.id = part2.link) A;
```

Results are roughly the same as yours: About 3x's slower. The, I read your stackoverflow link. Then I got to thinking: Look at the sample we used. We basically pushed MySQL to its limit to join 1M rows with 1M rows. This is the worst-case equi-join scenario. All things considered, the performance is pretty good.

I remember my college days where [I had to create a two-dimensional array using linked lists to construct a sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array). If a node did not exist in a particular coordinate, the default value for the array was defined as zero in the app. Then, imagine this. Creating a 1000x1000 sparse array where all 1000000 (1 million) coordinates had a nonzero value represented. Now, you had at least 2.002 million pointers mapping all adjacent nodes. This is in additional to the 1 million 4-byte integers for the data. Fetching a single value out of it required more CPU for navigation than the retrieval of the actual data.

Doing a INNER JOIN of 1M rows from part1 to part2 where part2 has absolutely every key requires more resources for navigation (temp table creation, key comparison, value population). Denormalizing can sometimes be demorializing if the right side of a LEFT JOIN isn't very sparse or the left side of the LEFT JOIN is huge. In your case, separating the original into part1 and part2 buys you nothing if they have to be frequently referenced together and in bulk. In other words, separating columns that do not form repeating groups isn't true normalization.

The 3 options I gave would do a world of good for part1 and fetching part2 on a row by row basis.

Think about the following cases:

- you only need some of the rows from part1

  - do you trust the MySQL Query Optimizer
  - do you refactor the query to get a cross section to part1 before joining to part2 ?
  - do you retrieve from part2 only one row at a time ?
- Using a LEFT JOIN and learning there is no part2 for a given part1

  - set default value in the app for part2 ?
  - populate part2 for that part1 ?

Giving more consideration to how you plan to retrieve data, how much data you need in a single query, and how you structure the query will become the determining factor as your seek good performance.

## EPILOGUE

You are not going to get better performance because of the cost to make the JOIN happen. [It's like trying to turn lead into gold (Theoretically possible, practically and financially impossible)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transmutation#History).

Your best bet is to leave the table in its original state.

Comment: -1, I tried all three options and none of them had a noticeable impact. You should be able to reproduce this yourself using the data population script I've posted in the question.